# ParseQuery findInBackground not calling completion handler in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm trying to query a very simple class on my Parse app:

```
public static void refreshNotifications(){
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Notification");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(List list, ParseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}
```

However, completion handler (neither `done` method) is never called, not even with an error. I was on Parse SDK 1.8, and I've updated to 1.10, but the issue still remains regardless of the version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // no error
                Log.d("DEBUG", "size of list " + list.size());
            } else {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried, still not called.

Comment: Wait, tried again after adding `query.whereEqualTo("receiver", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());` and it suddenly worked. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't have any idea, because I don't know what is your Notification class and other things.